# Strongly typed dataset: inserting many-to-many relations

Tags: many-to-many, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a many-to-many relation in 3 tables: **ProgramUserGroup** and **Feature** are the two main tables, and the link between them is **LinkFeatureWithProgramUserGroup**, where I have Foreign key relations to the two parent tables.

I have a dataset with inserts: I want to add a new row to ProgramUserGroup, and a related (existing) Feature to the LinkFeatureWithProgramUserGroup table.
When Inserting new rows, I'm setting the default id to -1:

```
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">   <DataSetUserGroup xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataSetUserGroup.xsd">
<ProgramUserGroup diffgr:id="ProgramUserGroup1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
  <id>-1</id>
  <Name>99999999999</Name>
  <Active>false</Active>
</ProgramUserGroup>
<LinkFeatureWithProgramUserGroup diffgr:id="LinkFeatureWithProgramUserGroup1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
  <id>-1</id>
  <Feature_id>7</Feature_id>
  <ProgramUserGroup_id>-1</ProgramUserGroup_id>
</LinkFeatureWithProgramUserGroup>  </DataSetUserGroup> </diffgr:diffgram>
```

while I'm updating the tables, I get an error:

"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK-LinkFeatu-Progr-7DCDAAA2". The conflict occurred in database "x", table "dbo.ProgramUserGroup", column 'id'."

The code for the update is the following:

```
 DataSetUserGroupTableAdapters.LinkFeatureWithProgramUserGroupTableAdapter lfa = new LinkFeatureWithProgramUserGroupTableAdapter();
 DataSetUserGroupTableAdapters.ProgramUserGroupTableAdapter pug = new ProgramUserGroupTableAdapter();

 pug.Update(dsUserGroup.ProgramUserGroup);
 lfa.Update(dsUserGroup.LinkFeatureWithProgramUserGroup);
```

if I check the ProgramUserGroup table's new row's ID, it has been updated from -1 to @@identity (like 1099), so it's okay - it inserts the new row.

But In the LinkFeatureWithProgramUserGroup table, the related ProgramUserGroup.ID value is still -1, it was not updated anyhow.

How could I force the update of the link table's keys as well?
I've tried

```
 pug.Update(dsUserGroup.ProgramUserGroup);
 dsUserGroup.Merge(dsUserGroup.ProgramUserGroup);
 lfa.Update(dsUserGroup.LinkFeatureWithProgramUserGroup);
```

But didn't solve the problem :(

Thanks,

b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, there's a work-around for this.

> **You need to tell your parent table's table-adapter to refresh the
>   data-table after update operation.
>   This is how you can do that.**

1. Open the properties of **ProgramUserGroupTableAdapter -> Default Select Query -> Advnaced options**. and Check the option of **Refresh the data table**. Save the adapter now. Now when you call update on table-adapter, the **data-table will be updated [refreshed] after the update operation** and will reflect the latest values from database table. **if the primary-key or any coloumn is set to auto-increment, the data-table will have those latest value post recent update.**
2. Now you can Call the update as pug.Update(dsUserGroup.ProgramUserGroup);
3. **Read latest values from the ProgramUserGroup coloumns and assign respective values into the child table before update**. This will work exactly the way you want.

[alt text http://ruchitsurati.net/files/tds1.png](http://ruchitsurati.net/files/tds1.png)

Comment: I've figured it out too - but thanks for the nice tutorial, I hope it will help others as well:)